# Count the number of consecutive TRUE values in R

Tags: r, boolean

I would like to count how many times I see two consecutive TRUE values in R. For example,

```
x <- c(T,F,T,T,F,F,T,F,T,F)
x
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

It would count 1 since there is a TRUE at position 3 and TRUE at position 4. If there are more than 2 consecutive TRUE, then I just want to count it only once, ie this vector

```
x <- c(T,F,T,T,T,F,T,F,T,F)
x
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

would still count 1. I started with looking at `rle()` but I got stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: something like `sum(rle(x)$length>1&rle(x)$values)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
with(rle(x), sum(lengths[values] >= 2))
```

---

**Explanation:**

As you are using Booleans, you can take profit of it. `rle(x)$lengths` will return how many consecutive times `TRUE` or `FALSE` happen in the vector. Example

```
x <- c(T,F,T,T,T,F,T,F,T,F,T,T)
rle(x)$lengths
[1] 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

Now you only want those values in this vector that correspond to `TRUE`s. `rle(x)$values` returns a vector with the order of appearance. Example:

```
rle(x)$values
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can use this to only get the `TRUE`s in the `lengths` vector:

```
rle(x)$lengths[rle(x)$values]
[1] 1 3 1 1 2
```

And the last step should be obvious: count how many of this values are grater or equal than 2. All together (with performance improvement):

```
with(rle(x), sum(lengths[values] >= 2))
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `cumsum` and `split` for that purpose as follows:

```
x <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
       TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
sum(lapply(split(x, cumsum(!x)), sum)>=2)
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another option with `rleid` from `data.table`.  The `rleid` gives a unique id to adjacent elements that are different, multiply with x, to convert the elements that corresponds to the `FALSE` in original vector to 0, get the frequency with `tabulate` convert to a logical vector (`==2`) and get the `sum`.

```
library(data.table)
sum(tabulate(rleid(x)*x)==2)
#[1] 1
```